# TableName using stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have some problems to passing the @TableName inside a Nearby procedure to use in one StoreLocator. I need to get in 3 tables. I have tested using QUOTENAME but the problem is always here. Can someone help me to fix this problem. Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNearbyTable]  
    @Table sysname, 
    @CenterLatitude FLOAT, 
    @CenterLongitude FLOAT, 
    @SearchDistance FLOAT, 
    @EarthRadius FLOAT
AS 

DECLARE @CntXAxis FLOAT
DECLARE @CntYAxis FLOAT
DECLARE @CntZAxis FLOAT 

SET @Table = RTRIM(@Table)   
SET @CntXAxis = COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * COS(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude)) 
SET @CntYAxis = COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude)) 
SET @CntZAxis = SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) 

SELECT TOP 100 *,  
       ProxDistance = @EarthRadius * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(glat, glon)*@CntXAxis + dbo.YAxis(glat, glon)*@CntYAxis + dbo.ZAxis(glat)*@CntZAxis)     
FROM  @Table  
WHERE @EarthRadius * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(glat, glon)*@CntXAxis + dbo.YAxis(glat, glon)*@CntYAxis + dbo.ZAxis(glat)*@CntZAxis) <= @SearchDistance
```

@Table or QUOTENAME(@Table) are not accepted. I have tested @Table as varchar(50) and similar. I'm not a SQLexpert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `EXEC()` to execute dynamic SQL. This should be the query you expect:

```
EXEC('
SELECT TOP 100 *,  
       ProxDistance = ' + @EarthRadius  + ' * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(glat, glon)*'
       + @CntXAxis + ' + dbo.YAxis(glat, glon)*'
       + @CntYAxis + ' + dbo.ZAxis(glat)*'
       + @CntZAxis + ')     
FROM  ' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + '
WHERE ' + @EarthRadius + ' * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(glat, glon)*'
       + @CntXAxis + ' + dbo.YAxis(glat, glon)*'
       + @CntYAxis + ' + dbo.ZAxis(glat)*'
       + @CntZAxis + ') <= ' + @SearchDistance)
```

BTW, when generating dynamic SQL like this, watch out for SQL injection possibilities (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx). The statement as I wrote it is free from injection risk because it quotes the only string that it includes.

Comment: Thanks, fixed where open/close brakets.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't allow you to do select from a dynamic table name.  You'll need to build an nvarchar(max) string and either use `exec()` or `sp_executesql`.  If you can, eliminate the need to pass a table name in dynamically for maintainability and performance reasons...

Comment: I need to use this procedure to seach nearby points in more than 10 Tables storing geoservices. Could you try to apply your suggestions in one easier sample? store the tablesNames in some list and use from there to execure one by one the sp_executesql in the main but maintainability is not great.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 100 *, ProxDistance = @EarthRadius * ACOS( dbo.XAxis(glat, glon)*@CntXAxis + dbo.YAxis(glat, glon)*@CntYAxis + dbo.ZAxis(glat)*@CntZAxis)
FROM  @Table'
```

Comment: +1: But you need to supply the variable values to the statement inside

Comment: Ok i have this 'Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar' but no other easier way to make this only for the TableName? This procedure use external functions and is not possible to supply variable values.